Trade volume significance
Is there a ratio that shows how much shares are outstanding vs how much of them are being traded? I feel that must be very important to look at am I right? if there is such a ratio what is a normal number for a megacap firm - i know it may differ but just give a very rough guess?

Not something I pay any attention to, but I don't "trade" -- I invest.

... which you do by trading just like everyone else

I feel that must be very important to look at - why do you feel that?

Suppose that you found this volume indicator.  How would you interpret it?

@upstream: Not especially. I buy and hold, and in fact I mostly buy index funds and hold those and don't care about daily noise.

@keshlam - How is telling us what you don't do relevant to answering the OP's question?

Frame challenge. I question whether this datum is actually useful for the retail investor. Measurability is not meaningfulness. GIGO

On-line brokerages that I have used routinely list the total market cap of the company and the number of shares traded today. I don't recall them calculating the percentage but you could easily do that arithmetic yourself.
For example, I have an account with Schwab. I own some stock in Amazon. I look up Amazon and it says current share price $188, market cap $2 trillion, average daily trade volume for past 10 days 52 million shares. I don't see a listing for shares outstanding but I could easily calculate that by dividing market cap by share price. $2 trillion / $188 ~= 11 billion. So if they're trading 52 million per day out of 11 billion that's about 0.5% per day. I have no idea if that's high or low or typical.
Does it matter? Interesting question. If I learned that someone with insider knowledge -- the founder or some top executive -- was selling all his shares, I'd suspect that he knows some bad news that isn't public yet. Or conversely if someone with insider knowledge was buying up shares. But besides that, if investors in general are trading more of a stock than usual or typical, what does that mean? Does it tell me anything I wouldn't know by reading general news about the company? If someone gave me this information about a wide range of stocks, I'm not sure what I'd do with it.
I'm not a professional broker and I don't claim to be a brilliant investor, so maybe there's something I'm missing. I guess if the sales volume on a stock suddenly went dramatically up or down, that means SOMETHING. I'm just not sure exactly what.

It means you may want to find out what, if anything, people are reacting to. Which may be something that happened in another company, or another country. And may be a paradoxical shift where people are reacting to how the world now differs from their prior assumptions, which can have unexpected effect. I think this number by itself is close to meaningless because it can mean almost anything.

@keshlam "... can mean almost anything" Yes, that's what I was trying to say. Does it mean SOMETHING? Sure. If the change in volume is more than normal random statistical variation, it must have had some cause. But what? It's not obvious that it would be good or bad. It could be either. I suppose you could say that ANY information you get about a stock means something and should be considered, but, etc.

As I said in the comments: GIGO. The fact that you can calculate a number does not automatically give it analytic or predictive value.   Daily Basis Stock Charts used to very carefully advertise as "the information you want!" -- by definition anyone who bought the service wanted it -- rather than "the information you need" because there was no good evidence that having the information would actually help the customers do better in the stock market.

@keshlam Sure. You could say that about almost any information anyone might give you about the stock market ... or anything else. I often get prospectuses (prospecti? whatever) that say, "Past performance is not a guarantee of future results." Maybe there's some regulation that requires them to say this, but it's just silly. OF COURSE past performance is not a GUARANTEE of future performance, but it's an awfully good indicator. If a fund has been posting 10% gains every year for the past 20 years, it's a fair assumption they'll continue to post 10% gains. Etc.

It's an assumption. Whether it is a good place be or not is a different question. Market conditions change. Competition changes. Technology changes. The world changes -- consider the post-covid market bust we're now recovering from, where my investments were down 30% for a while. The model is not the thing, and a nice curve only says things have been OK so far. Either dig much deeper to understand why the fund has been doing well, or don't overinvest in your guess. Volume in particular says very little beyond "people are paying attention, good or bad ."

If 10% gains every year for an extended time were enough, IBM would still own the majority of the computer industry, to take one obvious example. Every smooth curve looks predictable until it isn't.

@keshlam Yes, the world changes. That's why it's certainly true that past performance is not a GUARANTEE of future performance. The statement is technically true. But barring information to the contrary, the rational assumption is that present trends will continue. Do present trends ALWAYS continue? Of course not. That's why I'm skeptical of analyses that say, "If this trend continues for another 100 years ..." Like I've seen many predictions of the population of various countries 100 years from now based on assuming present birth rates continue. Possible, of course, but very debatable. ...

... But the flip side is people who predict that the world is going to radically change in the next few years. Like I've seen plenty of golly-wow articles about how some new technology will change the world in the next 5 years. They suppose that some new technology which is still in development today will not only be totally perfected within 5 years, but will be in mass production, available at a reasonable price, and all the infrastructure required to support it will be in place, all within 5 years. Happens sometimes ... but not often.

Moderation in all things. Including moderation.

@keshlam Yes. I read once, "Aristotle took moderation to an extreme."
